# How to change specific page slug with .HTACCESS?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, slug

I got a website script where it's very difficult to change page slugs.
So I thought I can do this with .htaccess.

I got my page url like - www.mysite.com/submit

So can I change this with .htaccess to www.mysite.com/create ???

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as your example can be easily done by `.htaccess`. Use this code in .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^submit/?$ create [L,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^create\$ /submit [L]
 or 
RewriteRule ^create$ /submit [L]